# PHP Print indefinite categories tree

Tags: php

I'm trying to print list of categories with indefinite subcategories.

Example:

```
    [
        [
            'categoryName' => 'Category1',
            'categoryUrl' => 'category-1',
            'subcategories' => [
                [
                    'categoryName' => 'Subcategory 1',
                    'categoryUrl' => 'sucbategory-1',
                    'subcategories' => [
                        [
                            'categoryName' => 'Subcategory subcategory 1',
                            'categoryUrl' => 'sucbategory-subcategory-1',
                            'subcategories' => [
                                [
                                    '....'
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        'categoryName' => 'Subcategory 2',
                        'categoryUrl' => 'sucbategory-12',
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

I was trying it with foreach inside foreach, etc...
Then I realised I don't know how many levels category tree will have.

Category1->Subcategory1->Subcategory Subcategory1-> Subcategory ... 1-> ??

Comment: Make a printing function and use recursion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP recursion: How to create a recursion in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931080/php-recursion-how-to-create-a-recursion-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

This is called a recursion. The idea is like this:

```
function printLeafs($node){
  echo $node->title;

  $leafs = getLeafs($node);
  foreach ($leafs as $leaf){
    printLeafs($leaf);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will print all using recursion.

```
function recurse($array) {

    foreach( $array as $one ) {
       echo $one['categoryName'] . '->' ;
       echo $one['categoryUrl'] . '->' ;

       if( isset($one['subcategories']) ) {
        if( is_array($one['subcategories'])) {
           recurse($one['subcategories']) ;
       }


       }
    }
};

recurse($array);
```

But in your code I've noted a problem, the following looks misplaced. In this case you are having categoryName not having a parent subcategories. If that a typo the above will work. Otherwise it wont.

```
'categoryName' => 'Subcategory 2',
'categoryUrl' => 'sucbategory-12',
```